# unable to start sbt in quickstart VM

Tags: scala, sbt

When i try to install sbt i quick start vm im getting below error.

```
vi  ~/.bash_profile
SBT_HOME=/home/cloudera/Scala/sbt
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin
```

after setting path also

the below error came

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ . ~/.bash_profile
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sbt
bash: /home/cloudera/Scala/sbt/bin/sbt: Permission denied
[cloudera@localhost ~]$
```

Please help me to resolve

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: it doesn't make sense to have permission denied on sbt, are you sure you are running it with the user you used to install it with? try with sudo sbt and make sure everything looks fine then update your question with the results

Comment: share the permissions on the directory and the user you are logged on as (ls -ltr should suffice for the directory where you setup sbt & the response from "whoami").

Answer (score 0):

**~/.bash_profile** should be like this--->> you have to set path to bin folder of sbt and eclipse

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
      . ~/.bashrc
```

fi**strong text**

```
# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:/opt/sbt/bin:/opt/scala-2.11.8/bin

export PATH
```